# div's next to each other, inline-block still causes linebreak without float

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I can't get it to work.
I have 1 screen container, in which I want 2 div's (1 content, 1 menu) next to each other.
1 div is positioned `relative`,

```
left:-830px.
```

So I can create a slide in effect using `overflow:hidden` and jQuery.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/4/

Does anyone know why this isn't working?
I've seen more examples using `inline-block` which causes two div's to be next to each other, why does it not work in my example?

Thanks in advance :)
P.S.  I don't want to use float

Comment: _"P.S. I don't want to use float"_ Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has nothing to do in this case with `inline-block` but rather that you have `#menu` as `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute`. [See fiddle with change](http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/5/).

A `position: relative` still causes the element to *occupy the same space in the layout* as it would if it were *static* ([here's a good explanation](http://designshack.net/articles/css/the-lowdown-on-absolute-vs-relative-positioning/)), it just shifts the element's display rendering by the adjusted amount (`-830px` in your case) *relative to itself* (where it would have been if static).

So the second element in your case is being displaced by the "void" left from where the first element is still taking up layout space, but has been shifted outside it for rendering.

**Another solution** would be to keep the `relative` on `#menu` and set `margin-left: -830px` on the `#content` div to "pull" it over the space the `#menu` layout is taking up, as seen in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/6/)

Both solutions offered, when the menu animates, will "overlay" the `#content` assuming `#menu` is given a `z-index: 1` ([see 1st solution fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/8/) and [2nd solution](http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/10/) (with menu at `-430px`), whereas if you wanted the second solution offered to "push" the `#content` down below the menu on animation, then you would also have to change the `margin-left` back to `0` at the time of menu animation, like [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/13/).

Comment: Well, the root cause is certainly `position: relative;`, but `display: inline-block;` affects it a bit because of rendered whitespace. For instance, set `#menu` to `width:4px;`, and set `font-size:0;` on `#screen_container` (to get rid of rendered whitespace due to `inline-block`). Then toggle `#menu`'s `relative` position on and off to see the effect described above about `position:relative;`. Remove the `font-size` rule (to render the whitespace), and the `#content` div will *always* be shoved down because of the rendered whitespace and the set widths. http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/7/

Comment: Holy cow, I thought positioning absolute was relative to the whole browser window. Where positioning relative was relative to the parent div. Soooo positioning absolute is still relative to the parent. And positioning relative works the same like absolute only it uses it's original space (top:0 left:0) AND the new space(left:-830px)? So it's like it's in its static position, but it is visible in the -830px, like an optical illusion?
Any way you just learned me a crucial new thing and my problem is fixed, thank you!

Comment: @vincentkleine Relative positioning means that the element with `position: relative` will be moved relative to its static position, as ScottS explained. It also means that any `position: absolute` *descendent* elements will be positioned relatively to the `position: relative` element.

Comment: @vincentkleine: `position: absolute` is relative to the nearest parent that also has position other than `static` set. So because `#screen_container` is set to `position: relative` any children of it that are `absolute` position themselves off of that element, rather than the `body` element. This would be true if `#screen_container` were set to `absolute` or `fixed` as well. Again, any position other than static.